# Hoare's partition not working correctly (quicksort)

Tags: c++, algorithm, quicksort

So after following the quicksort and hoares partition algorithm from Cormen, this is the code that I was able to produce.  The array comes out partly sorted with uninitialized elements/garbage elements and I can't for the life of me figure out why... I thought I followed the algorithm exactly as the book writes it.

Here is the pseudocode straight from the book:

```
HOARE-PARTITION(A, p, r)
1 x = A[p]
2 i = p - 1
3 j = r + 1
4 while TRUE
5     repeat
6        j = j - 1
7     until A[j] <= x
8     repeat
9        i = i + 1
10    until A[i] >= x
11    if i < j
12        exchange A[i] with A[j]
13    else return j
```

And here is the C++ code I translated it into:

```
void quickSort(int arr[], int p, int r){
    if(p < r){
        int q = hoare_partition(arr, p, r);
        quickSort(arr, p, q-1);
        quickSort(arr, q+1, r);
    }
}

int hoare_partition(int arr[], int p, int r){
    int x = arr[p];
    int i = p - 1;
    int j = r + 1;
    while(true){
        do{
            j--;
        }while(arr[j] > x);
        do{
            i++;
        }while(arr[i] < x);
        if(i < j){
            int temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = temp;
        }
        else 
            return j;
    }
}
```

Im using the following to test it

```
cout << endl << endl << "Testing quicksort" << endl;
int tarr[10] = {2, 30, 1, 99, 46, 33, 48, 67, 23, 76};
quickSort(tarr, 0, 10);
cout << "arr after quicksort: ";
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    cout <<  tarr[i] << " ";
}
cout << endl;
```

The output

```
arr after quicksort: -2146162183 1 2 23 30 33 46 48 67 76
```

Any help is appreciated ahead of time...thanks

### EDIT

Changing the test case call to quickSort(arr, 0, 9) fixed it for this situation.

However, with a reverse sorted array as the input this is the output:

```
arr2 is:
30 29 28 27 26 25 24 23 22 21 20 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
arr2 after quicksort :
1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19 20 21 18 22 16 23 14 24 12 25 10 26 8 27 6 28 4 29 2 30
```

using this test code:

```
int arr2[30];
fillArrayReverse(arr2, 30);
cout << "arr2 is :" << endl;
for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++){
    cout << arr2[i] << " ";
}
cout << endl;
quickSort(arr2, 0, 29);
cout << "arr2 after quicksort: " << endl;
for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++){
    cout << arr2[i] << " ";
}
cout << endl;
```

Comment: You do need to watch for 0-based arrays as opposed to 1-based arrays, as you note in a comment to the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a problem with your test code. The third parameter should be the index of the last element, not the number of elements:

```
quickSort(tarr, 0, 9);
```

You're reading past the end of the array.

For more information about Hoare partitioning, Quicksort and Cormen etc, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7198121/quicksort-and-hoare-partition).

The simple fix for the other problems you're having is to change hoare_partition() to `return i` instead of j. See the link for more details (it's an error in the book reportedly).

Comment: In the book it says "To sort an entire array A, the initial call is QUICKSORT(A, 1, A.length)." But then again the book goes by 1-indexed arrays. So that must be why it's using the length as opposed to length-1....

Comment: It still doesn't work on a reverse sorted array, made an edit to my question with details

Answer (score 6):

The psuedocode in the book is correct. The issue is not that `j` was returned (this was correct), but in the `quickSort` function itself. It should actually read as follows:

```
void quickSort( int arr[], int p, int r )
{
    if( p < r )
    {
        int q = hoare_partition( arr, p, r );
        quickSort( arr, p, q );
        quickSort( arr, q + 1, r );
    }
}
```

Note that we remove `q - 1` in the first call to `quickSort`, and replace it with just `q`. Beforehand we were essentially skipping the pivot point and only sorting items around it. I noticed this discrepancy after taking a look at the Hoare Partition psuedocode on quick sort on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Hoare_partition_scheme).

Comment: Thank you for posting this, the other answer is clearly wrong by stating you should return i instead of j. The point of Hoare's is not to separate the array into `[items smaller than partition] partitioning element [items larger than or equal to partition]`, it's to separate the array into `[items smaller] [items larger or equal]`. As you mentioned, we then quicksort the two subarrays - but unlike the Lomuto partition, the partitioning element is not already in the correct place so it must be included in the recursive calls to quicksort.