# QuickSort Hoare's partitioning not working

Tags: sorting, quicksort, partition

Hi I'v been trying to write Hoare's partition function for like 5 hours now. I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7198121/quicksort-and-hoare-partition) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29025158/hoares-partition-not-working-correctly-quicksort) and even straight up copied the "correct" function from these questions and it's still nowhere near the answer. Here is my "translated" code from Cormen's book.

```
int Hpartition(int A[], int p, int r){
int x = A[p];
int i = p - 1;
int j = r + 1;
while(true){
    do{
        j--;
    }while(A[j] <= x);
    do{
        i++;
    }while(A[i] >= x);
    if(i < j){
        swap(A[i],A[j]);
    }
    else
        return j;
 }
}
```

QuickSort:

```
void qs(int A[],int p,int r){
if(p<r){
    int q=Hpartition(A,p,r);
    qs(A,p,q-1);
    qs(A,q+1,r);
}
}
```

Main:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
int tab[10];

for(int k=0;k<10;k++){
    cin >> tab[k];
}


qs(tab,0,9);

for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    cout << tab[i] << " ";
}
return 0;
}
```

For this data :

> 2 4 1 3 5 7 6 8 10 9

It produces this result:

> 2 4 9 3 5 7 6 8 10 1

Based on the previous questions regarding the topic I know there may be some mistakes in the book. But even when I apply the answers from the previous questions it just won't work .

Here is the algorithm from the book:

```
HOARE-PARTITION(A, p, r)
1 x = A[p]
2 i = p - 1
3 j = r + 1
4 while TRUE
5     repeat
6        j = j - 1
7     until A[j] <= x
8     repeat
9        i = i + 1
10    until A[i] >= x
11    if i < j
12        exchange A[i] with A[j]
13    else return j
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: `do..while` and `repeat..until` use inverted breaking conditions: `while(x)` repeats as long as `x` is true, `until(x)` stops, once `x` becomes true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 error translating code from book:

```
do{
     j--;
  }while(A[j] <= x);
```

You should inverse this:

```
do{
     j--;
  }while(A[j] > x);
```

The same with:

```
do{
     i++;
  }while(A[i] >= x);
```

And one more here:

```
qs(A,p,q-1);
qs(A,q+1,r);
```

Change to:

```
qs(A,p,q);
qs(A,q+1,r);
```

Comment: Thank you soo much. If you come to Poland , contact me. Beer on me!!