# Java Quicksort Partition method

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I am writing a Java quicksort method. my code currently is as follows

```
    public class Quicksort {

   public static void main(String[ ] args)
   {
      final String BLANKS = "  "; // A String of two blanks
      int i;                      // Array index

      int[ ] data = { 1000, 80, 10, 50, 70, 60, 90, 20, 30, 40, 0, -1000 };

      // Print the array before sorting:
      System.out.println("Here is the entire original array:");
      for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
         System.out.print(data[i] + BLANKS);
      System.out.println( );

      // Sort the numbers, and print the result with two blanks after each number.
      quicksort(data, 1, data.length-2);
      System.out.println("I have sorted all but the first and last numbers.");
      System.out.println("The numbers are now:");
      for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
         System.out.print(data[i] + BLANKS);
      System.out.println( );
   }
```

Quicksort Method

```
    public static void quicksort(int[ ] data, int first, int n)
   {
      int pivotIndex; // Array index for the pivot element
      int n1;         // Number of elements before the pivot element
      int n2;         // Number of elements after the pivot element

      if (n > 1)
      {
         // Partition the array, and set the pivot index.
         pivotIndex = partition(data, first, n);

         // Compute the sizes of the two pieces.
         n1 = pivotIndex - first;
         n2 = n - n1 - 1;

         // Recursive calls will now sort the two pieces.
         quicksort(data, first, n1);
         quicksort(data, pivotIndex + 1, n2);
      }
   }
```

Partition Method

```
   private static int partition(int[ ] data, int first, int n){ 
      int low = first;
      int high = n;
      int pivot = data[low];

      while(low < high){
         low ++;

         while(low <= high && data[low] < pivot){
            low ++;
         }
         while(high >= low && data[high] > pivot){
            high--;
         }
         if(low<=n && low < high){
            int temp = data[low];
            data[low] = data[high];
            data[high] = temp;
         }
      }
      return low;  
   }//end partition

}//end class
```

When I currently run the program i get a result of 
1000  80  0  10  70  60  90  20  30  40  50  -1000
After several different attempts and rewrites of the partition method I still cannot get the array to sort properly. The task is to have the whole array sorted except the first and last numbers.

Comment: When I ran this, I got a `StackOverflowError`

Comment: Get any reliable implementation of partition. Yours contains a lot of mistakes. Omits the first element, uses n=subarray size as right index and so on.

Answer (score 2):

***Quicksort Method***

```
public static void quicksort(int[ ] data, int first, int last){
          if (last-first > 1){
             // Partition the array, and set the pivot index.
             pivotIndex = partition(data, first, n);
             //n1 = pivotIndex - first; //problem is here 
             //  n2 = n - n1 - 1;       // and here 
             // Recursive calls will now sort the two pieces.
             quicksort(data, first, pivotIndex);
             quicksort(data, pivotIndex + 1, last);
          }
       }
```

***Partition Method*** actual Hoare's partition.

```
  private static int partition(int[ ] data, int first, int last){ 
  int low = first-1;
  int high = n+1;
  int pivot = data[low];

    while (true) {

        do {
            low++;
        }
        while (data[low] < pivot);

        do {
            high--;
        }
        while (data[j] > pivot);

        if (low < high) {
            int temp = data[low];
            data[low] = data[high];
            data[high] = temp;
        } else {
            return high;
        }
    }

}
```

I have updated both the functions now you just need to call.

```
int[ ] data = { 1000, 80, 10, 50, 70, 60, 90, 20, 30, 40, 0, -1000 };
quicksort(data, 1, data.length-2);
```

[Here is a good explanation of Hoare partition.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7198121/quicksort-and-hoare-partition)

Comment: better answer would be explaining his mistakes rather than copypasting a ready and well-known code snippet

Comment: @Ashish he is trying to implement hoare's partition you have implemented lomuto partition

Comment: @GuhanNagarajan ah my bad Thanks, I didn't know about Hoare's partition method :)

Comment: Thanks for comments I have updated the answer. The problem was in quicksort method only, will test partition method and update my answer once I find the issue in it . until then I have given correct partition method from the answer in a link.