# query about hoares partition : boundary check

Tags: quicksort, partition

I found lots of the hoare partition implementation for quick sorting, it didn't do the boundary check while finding the larger item or smaller item comparing to the pivot item. anyone know why?

For example, below is from https://www.techiedelight.com/quick-sort-using-hoares-partitioning-scheme/. While increasing i, decreasing j, the a[i] might be out of upper boundary when the array a is already a descending array.

```
 
# Partition using Hoare's Partitioning scheme
def partition(arr, low, high):
 
    pivot = arr[low]
    (i, j) = (low - 1, high + 1)
 
    while True:
 
        while True:
            i = i + 1
            if arr[i] >= pivot:
                break
 
        while True:
            j = j - 1
            if arr[j] <= pivot:
                break
 
        if i >= j:
            return j
 
        swap(arr, i, j)
```

my understanding is to add the boundary check for i, and j, like below:

```
# Partition using Hoare's Partitioning scheme
def partition(arr, low, high):
 
    pivot = arr[low]
    (i, j) = (low - 1, high + 1)
 
    while True:
 
        while True:
            i = i + 1
            if arr[i] >= pivot and i < high:
                break
 
        while True:
            j = j - 1
            if arr[j] <= pivot and j > low:
                break
 
        if i >= j:
            return j
 
        swap(arr, i, j)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [QuickSort and Hoare Partition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7198121/quicksort-and-hoare-partition)

Comment: See in particular https://stackoverflow.com/a/7198223/341994

Comment: Thank you matt. In the links you mentioned, I cannot find to add that boundary check in those implementations.